# Bootstrap Icons are not quadratic

Tags: html, css

I am using the [Bootstrap Icons](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/). However, I have one problem: The icon font works by appying a `::before` selector to an `i` element. But while an icon with a font size of 24 pixels is exactly 24 by 24 pixels, the `i` element has some extra space on the bottom, and I cannot find a way to fix this.

Here is an example with a red border. You can inspect the element to see that the selector itself has the right size, but the element not.

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

i {
    font-size: 24px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.6.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Decrease the line-height: `line-height: 22px;`

Comment: Could you also explain to me why it works that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the DOM, you'll see that the `<i>` has a height of `28px` while the icon itself is only `24px`.

To ensure the element is the same height, I'd just add a `height` property, the same as the icon, for example:

```css
i {
    font-size: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

i {
    font-size: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.bi::before {
    vertical-align: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.6.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Since the Bootstraps adds the following css:

```css
vertical-align: -.125em;
```

The icons won't be centert perfectly, we can remove that by adding

```css
.bi::before {
    vertical-align: 0px !important;
}
```